# JTable date value to jspinner

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

i have displayed a date value formatted MM/dd/yyyy and i want it to display to jsinner on jtablemouseclickedevent. how would i do that? i tried it with this code but i get an error:

my jtable has 5 columns

```
ID = int type
Username = String type
Password = String type
Website = String type
Date Encoded = date/time type (MM/dd/yyyy)
```

this is my code:

```
jLabel5.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
jTextField4.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
jTextField5.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
jTextField6.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
**jSpinner1.setValue(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 4));**
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :) :) :)

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure `getValueAt()` returns a `Date` object and not a `String`?

Answer (score 0):

You use `SpinnerDateModel` and pass a String as the value (`jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString()`) instead of a date. Convert the string to a date (or maybe you even got a date already) before passing it to the spinner.