# jtable value to jspinner not displayed

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

problem is can't get the value displayed from jtable to jspinner. here is my jtablemouseclickedeven

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
if(evt.getClickCount()==1){
    jLabel5.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
    jTextField4.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
    jTextField5.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
    jTextField6.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
    jSpinner1.setValue(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
}
}
```

jspinner is formatted as MM/dd/yyyy so the jtable also...

thanks to anyone who could help me again...

here is the error i get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal value
        at javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel.setValue(SpinnerDateModel.java:440)
        at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:329)
        at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm.jTable1MouseClicked(MainForm.java:930)
        at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm.access$1600(MainForm.java:34)
        at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm$17.mouseClicked(MainForm.java:337)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4247)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable date value to jspinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375278/jtable-date-value-to-jspinner)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the second duplicate already.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.  If you continue to ask the same question (or slightly different variants of it) it is considered abuse of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is another duplicate, I'll try again: You use `SpinnerDateModel` and pass a String as the value (`jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString()`) instead of a date. Convert the string to a date (or maybe you even got a date already) before passing it to the spinner.

Edit: I posted this answer to the original question, so a moderator might delete this duplicate.